# Git log for the next change on a specific file line in a remote branch

Tags: git, ffmpeg, git-diff, git-remote, git-log

I'm exploring the git history of the project [FFMpeg](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg). I got the changes performed on each file between the commits `517573a67088b5c7a25c18373434e3448892ee93` and `80bb65fafab1d2f5f58a8453c6334c784ee27c08` by creating a patch with the command:

```
git diff 80bb65fafab1d2f5f58a8453c6334c784ee27c08..c5079bf3bccd24bf8ed45ff47ff4071fd09e9fd8 -p > my.patch
```

Now, for instance, I know that the file `doc/examples/encode_video.c` has been modified at row `149` and I would get the only the next commit after `c5079bf3bccd24bf8ed45ff47ff4071fd09e9fd8` that modifies this line. Considering that some commits are on remotes, I'm using the command:

```
git log -L149,149: doc/examples/encode_video.c -1 c5079bf3bccd24bf8ed45ff47ff4071fd09e9fd8..HEAD --remotes
```

but git returns the message:

```
fatal: More than one commit to dig from: origin/HEAD and HEAD?
```

I think the problem is that I'm trying to log a commit on a remote, not on the master branch, but it's just a speculation. How can I solve it?

Comment: What version of Git are you using ? I do not get this error message on my side.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not just fetching from remote and using your local copy to compare with?

Comment: Yes, the reason Is that I've to do this operation for several commits in different versions of the repo. So, fetching all the remotes will slow down dramatically the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The doc for the line log functionality (`git log -L`) [says](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt--Lltstartgtltendgtltfilegt):

> `-L<start>,<end>:<file>`
> `-L:<funcname>:<file>`
>
> Trace the evolution of the line range given by `<start>,<end>`, or by the function name regex `<funcname>`, within the `<file>`. You may not give any  pathspec limiters. This is currently limited to a walk starting from a single revision, i.e., you may only give zero or one positive revision arguments, and `<start>` and `<end>` (or `<funcname>`) must exist in the starting revision. [...]

Notice that there is no space between the colon and the filename, so your command should be:

```
git log -L149,149:doc/examples/encode_video.c -1 c5079bf3bccd24bf8ed45ff47ff4071fd09e9fd8..HEAD --remotes
```

With this syntax I get the same error message as you. The doc states that the line-log functionality is limited to a revision walk starting from a single revision. Here you are giving a range (`c5079bf3bccd24bf8ed45ff47ff4071fd09e9fd8..HEAD`), as well as the `--remotes` arguments, whose docs says:

> Pretend as if all the refs in `refs/remotes` are listed on the command line as `<commit>`.

So you are not at all giving a single revision to `git log`, hence the error message.

---

Now to try to get the answer you are looking for. `git log` does not talk to the server, so if you do not have all commits locally (you are working in an old clone, for example), you should `git fetch` first, as joanis points out.

Then, you could start by looking at all the commits that touch the file you are interested in between `c5079bf3bccd24bf8ed45ff47ff4071fd09e9fd` and what the master branch was pointing to last time you fetched it :

```
$ git log --oneline c5079bf3bccd24bf8ed45ff47ff4071fd09e9fd8..origin/master  doc/examples/encode_video.c
1698cd8422 doc/examples/encode_video: add explanations in comments.
```

OK, there is a single commit touching that file. Let's take a look at its content:

```
$ git show 1698cd8422 | head -20
commit 1698cd8422c8a363e25dd94beb61c0a6d68bd67c
Author: Nicolas George <george@nsup.org>
Date:   Mon Aug 16 15:05:59 2021 +0200

    doc/examples/encode_video: add explanations in comments.

diff --git a/doc/examples/encode_video.c b/doc/examples/encode_video.c
index 908eb203d5..939ed68324 100644
--- a/doc/examples/encode_video.c
+++ b/doc/examples/encode_video.c
@@ -155,12 +155,25 @@ int main(int argc, char **argv)
     for (i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
         fflush(stdout);
 
-        /* make sure the frame data is writable */
+        /* Make sure the frame data is writable.
+           On the first round, the frame is fresh from av_frame_get_buffer()
+           and therefore we know it is writable.
+           But on the next rounds, encode() will have called
+           avcodec_send_frame(), and the codec may have kept a reference to
```

OK, so the first hunk starts at line 155. So here is an answer to your query: there is no commit in the range `c5079bf3bccd24bf8ed45ff47ff4071fd09e9fd8..origin/HEAD` that touch line 149 in the file `doc/examples/encode_video.c`.

**EDIT** after experimenting a bit more, it seems the line log functionality does support being given a range. So this invocation would give you the same answer:

```
git log -L149,149:doc/examples/encode_video.c -1 c5079bf3bccd24bf8ed45ff47ff4071fd09e9fd8..origin/HEAD
```

The command returns nothing since as noted above no commits in that range modify line 149 in that file.

Comment: Thank you for the extensive explanation. Before trying this solution (so fetching time by time) I was trying to use `git blame` like: `git blame doc/examples/encode_video.c -L 149,149 --reverse c5079bf3bccd24bf8ed45ff47ff4071fd09e9fd8` but in this case I'm afraid that the line checked belongs to the `HEAD` instead of the older commit. In fact the output is: `b7f6a933fa4 (Michael Goulet 2022-06-16 10:14:50 +0200 149)     if (ret < 0) {` Any workaround on this? –

Comment: Here you are using `git blame --reverse`, which according to its [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame#Documentation/git-blame.txt---reverseltrevgtltrevgt) is used to "Walk history forward instead of backward. Instead of showing the revision in which a line appeared, this shows the last revision in which a line has existed." This line *has not disappeared* in the range you give, and so the command returns the last commit in the range. This is a little confusing, I agree.